# Extract specific word which contain in another from string

Tags: php

I have the following strings.
I want to extract Men, Women from these strings?

```
$str = "Men&#039;s Fragrances";
$str= "Women&#039;s Fragrances";
$str= "Testers &amp; Unboxed Women&#039;s";
$str= "Testers &amp; Unboxed Men&#039;s";
```

I'm trying with this but not working!

```
if(strpos( $str, 'men') > 0 && strpos($str, 'women') == false ){
             $gender = 'men';
         }else{
$gender = 'women';
}
```

Comment: Remember that computers are very literal, and don't know what letters and words _mean_ - the string "men" and the string "Men" are not the same, but the string "women" _does_ contain the string "men".

Comment: If want to do it case-insensitive you could use [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Comment: in this case i want to extract gender from string. The string I'll we try to use strtolower to unify the string...

Answer (score 0):

You compare with [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and lowercase `men`, so comparison is *case sensitive* (and `strpos` can return 0, so `strpos($str, 'men') > 0` for first string will fail)

Use [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) or convert string to lowercase for *case insensitive* results:

```php
$str = strtolower($str);

$gender = str_contains($str, 'men') && !str_contains($str, 'women'))
    ? 'men'
    : 'women';
```

---

Please note that your code will report `$gender` as `women` for `$str = 'Hello World';`